# Sharing targeted xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I use the following command to share a link, but with this command opens a box with apps for me to share. I want when I share it already go straight to facebook, without going through this box

```
    void OnTapped4(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        CrossShare.Current.ShareLink(link, "teste", titulo);
    }
```

Need to do direct shares to facebook, whatsapp, twitter and email

I have this command plus it works only on xamarin android, in xamarin forms it would no work

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText,"titulo");
sendIntent.SetType("text/plain");
sendIntent.SetPackage("com.facebook.orca");
StartActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Use a dependency service to call the native Android code:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you do not want to display the `ActionSend` `Intent` but open Facebook directly with the sharable content? If so, and as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), that is not possible, as _"it is up to the receiver of this action to ask the user where the data should be sent."_

Comment: I wanted to see if I could do this by using CrossShare

Answer (score 0):

I found the following example where I did on android and it worked, now I want to do this in IOS how can I get it to go to whatsapp

Android

```
public class ShareService : IShareService
{
    public void SharePageLink(string url)
    {
        var context = Forms.Context;
        Activity activity = context as Activity;

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
        share.SetType("text/plain");
        share.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);
        share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Brusselslife");
        share.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
        share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, url);


        activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(share, "Share link!"));
    }
}
```

In IOS where to put this 'com.whatsapp'

```
public class ShareService : IShareService
{
    public void SharePageLink(string url)
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var rootViewController = window.RootViewController;

        //SetPackage

         var activityViewController = new UIActivityViewController(new NSString[] { new NSString(url) }, null);

        activityViewController.ExcludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] {
            UIActivityType.AirDrop,
            UIActivityType.Print,
            UIActivityType.Message,
            UIActivityType.AssignToContact,
            UIActivityType.SaveToCameraRoll,
            UIActivityType.AddToReadingList,
            UIActivityType.PostToFlickr,
            UIActivityType.PostToVimeo,
            UIActivityType.PostToTencentWeibo,
            UIActivityType.PostToWeibo
        };

        rootViewController.PresentViewController(activityViewController, true, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got any solution?